# ArcGIS: recode to different geography

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

What is the easiest way to recode data from one geography to another?

For example, if I have population data for one set of polygons, and I'd like to deduce it for different polygons - a bit like a spatial join but taking account of partial overlaps.  For this job I am willing to assume even distribution of population over area.

I imagine you could produce a raster then use zonal statistics to convert back to polygons, but is there a quicker way?

Comment: Just so I understand you correctly, will your new polygons be the same size (like a grid)? Then are you wanting to do a proportional spatial join.  e.g. If a grid cell takes up 30% area of your original polygon, then it should have 30% of the population total?

Comment: No, the polygons will be different sizes, but your statement about overlapping area still holds true for the portion of the output geography that overlaps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ArcGIS 10.1 [Tabulate Intsersection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000044000000) (in the Analysis toolbox) solves this problem.  It produces a table output which can be joined to the desired output geometry.

Thanks are due to radouxju whose answer pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You did not specify your version, but if you have a recent ArcGIS and polygons in the same layer you can use the [polygon neighbour](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Polygon_Neighbors/000800000045000000/) tool. It can give you the area of overlap between each polygon and the overlapping ones. then you can extract the information that you need from the resulting table and join it by attribute to recover the area weighted characteristics.

Comment: Polygon neighbour only appears to take a single geometry input.  But thanks, because you led me to discover `tabulate intersection` which looks like it does the job.

Comment: Looks like I didn't understand exactly what you needed, but I'm glad it helped. I suggest that you post your comment as an answer to your own question.